# pg-promise transaction response

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

So I'm a little stuck here.

I have an object such as:

```
var lineItems = [
    {
      id: 1,
      quantity: 10
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      quantity: 15
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      quantity: 22
    }
]
```

now what I need to do is loop through this in a pg-promise SQL transaction to ensure that the row item in the database quantity for the associated id is >= the object items, so:

```
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = $1 AND quantity >= $2, [1,10],
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = $1 AND quantity >= $2, [2,15],
SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id = $1 AND quantity >= $2, [4,22]
```

if I receive 3 results then the object is true and i'm able to insert the request with

```
INSERT INTO orders SET a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, items = lineItems::json etc RETURNING id;
```

and of course if i have less results than in the lineItems object then I don't bother with the `INSERT` statement, and simply return a `'item id: 4, quantity:22 doesn't have enough inventory to perform your request...`

I was initially using:

```
db.tx(function(t)){
  return this.batch([
    checkInventory
  ])
    .then(function(inv){
      console.log( inv );
    });
})
.then(function(results){
  console.log( results );
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.log( error );
});
```

where `checkInventory` is the function I'm calling as

```
var checkInventory = function(){
    console.log( '|-------------------------------------|' );
    console.log( 'LINE ITEMS >> ', lineItems );
    var query = [], sql = ''; 
    for( var i = 0; i < lineItems.length; i++ ){
        sql += 'SELECT quantity FROM pim_inventory WHERE';
        sql += ' product_id = $1 AND quantity >= $2;';

        var pquery = [
            lineItems[i].id,
            lineItems[i].quantity
        ];

        query.push(this.one(sql, pquery));
    }

    console.log( 'invQUERY >> ', query );
    return query;
};
```

which is generating the following errors:

```
(node:44810) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 3): QueryResultError: Multiple rows were not expected.
(node:44810) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 4): error: syntax error at or near "product_id"
|-------------------------------------|
EVENTS >>  [ [ Promise {
      <rejected> QueryResultError: Multiple rows were not expected.
        at QueryResultError.Error (native)
        at new QueryResultError (/Users/directtap-dev/www/GitHub/v1.02/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/errors.js:13:22)
        at Query.callback (/Users/directtap-dev/www/GitHub/v1.02/node_modules/pg-promise/lib/index.js:629:38)
        at Query.handleReadyForQuery (/Users/directtap-dev/www/GitHub/v1.02/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:89:10)
        at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/directtap-dev/www/GitHub/v1.02/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:163:19)
        at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
        at Connection.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/directtap-dev/www/GitHub/v1.02/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:109:12)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) },
    Promise { <rejected> [Object] } ] ]
```

any ideas?

Comment: When you use this: `this.one(sql, pquery)` you create requests each expects exactly one row back, but at least one of them returns more than one row, hence the error `Multiple rows were not expected.`. See the method's API, it's all there.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask too many questions at once, you are likely to get in multiple errors in the midst. Try solving one problem at a time.

---

In your code there are at least 5 problems, evidently...

**Problem 1**

When you use this: `this.one(sql, pquery)` you create requests each expects exactly one row back, but at least one of them returns more than one row, hence the error `Multiple rows were not expected.`. See the [method's API](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.one), it's all there.

**Problem 2**

You use your function `checkInventory` to generate an array of promises, which is fine, but then instead of passing it into method `batch` directly, you do `batch([checkInventory])`, which results in `batch([[promises]])`, which doesn't get resolved because of it.

**Problem 3**

You use `checkInventory` rather than a function, which is invalid. You should call `batch(checkInventory())`.

**Problem 4**

You obviously do not show the complete code, as somewhere you do not chain the promises you create, which results in loose promises, and then `Unhadled promise rejection` in the end.

**Problem 5**

Some of the values you are passing for `product_id` are invalid, hence the server-level error about it.

Comment: Thanx Vitaly - I'm not understanding what you mean by 'instead of passing it into method ```batch```  because I didn't realize I was doing that incorrectly. can you give me an example of how to pass it into the method batch directly?

Comment: You are supposed to pass in an array of promises, but instead you are passing in an array of arrays of promises.

Comment: yes thank you, i''m just realizing that :) i need to pass in:

SELECT * FROM inventory a = $1 AND b >=$2, [ [1,10], [2,15], [4,22] ]